# Create a sequence of numbers and reset itself when certain number is reached

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which first column has 11 rows, i want to create a second column and count from 1 to 4 and then reset the count and start from 1 to 4 and stop counting when reaches the last row.

for instance, I have `df['item']` and the code should create a `df['new column']`:

```
df['item']=        [a b c d e f g h i j k]    
df['new column'] = [1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3]
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Maybe use `for i in range(1,4)` - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: look in to itertools repeat combined with pd concat, seems straightforward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use modulo with `4` and add `1`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'item': list('abcdefghijk')})
#default index solution
df['new column'] = df.index % 4 + 1
#general solution
#df['new column'] = np.arange(len(df)) % 4 + 1
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   item  new column
0     a           1
1     b           2
2     c           3
3     d           4
4     e           1
5     f           2
6     g           3
7     h           4
8     i           1
9     j           2
10    k           3
```

If large DataFrame performance is for each solution different:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1000000)})

In [307]: %timeit df['new column'] = (len(df)*[1, 2, 3, 4])[:len(df)]
363 ms ± 15.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [308]: %timeit df['new column1'] = df.index % 4 + 1
35.1 ms ± 416 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [309]: %timeit df['new column2'] = np.arange(len(df)) % 4 + 1
14.4 ms ± 165 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the operation df.index%4?. df.index by itself is a sequence of numbers and "%" which gives the remainder, so how putting the two together results in the pattern above?

Comment: @Ismael Ochoa Yes, you are right, index starts by 0, so it return 0,1,2,3 as remaider, so is necessary add 1 for 1,2,3,4 pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can repeat the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` `n` times simply by doing `n * [1, 2, 3, 4]`. Thus your new column is created with:

```
df['new column'] = (len(df)*[1, 2, 3, 4])[:len(df)]
```